# Using GDB convenience vars with monitor commands

Tags: c, arm, gdb, embedded, segger-jlink

I'm using `arm-none-eabi-gdb` and `JLinkGDBServer` to debug an embedded system using a [JLink SAM-ICE](https://www.segger.com/jlink-oem-versions.html).  The embedded system uses an [ATSAMD21](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42181-SAM-D21_Datasheet.pdf) MCU.

From reading page 25 of the [JLinkGDBServer documentation](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~sulo/harjoitustyo/ymparisto/JLinkGDBServer.pdf), I learned that I can read a memory location on the microcontroller using the following command:

```
    (gdb) monitor MemU32 0x0000
    Reading from address 0x00000000 (Data = 0x20004000)
```

And that works great.  Now, the issue I'm having is that I need to automate this and read a range of memories, so I tried to do this:

```
    (gdb) set $addr = 0x804000
    (gdb) monitor MemU32 $addr
    Expected an decimal digit (0-9)
```

But clearly that's not working for me.  Does anyone know what's going on?  How can I read memory locations like this?

Comment: Why not use normal `print` command? Just define an absolute symbol in your code or the linker script.

Comment: I am trying to write a gdb script that will set the flash fuses in the SAMD21.  In order to do this, I need to read the memory from addresses `0x804000` to `0x804007` so that I can bit mask them.

Comment: Looks like no substitutions are done in a `monitor` command. Try `eval "monitor MemU32 %#x", $addr`

Comment: You can use gdb's Python interpreter to accomplish such complex tasks.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll check that out soon.  Is there a C programming interface for gdb instead of python?

Comment: @Olaf Darnit!  Python is not supported by `arm-none-eabi-gdb`.  I might try to pipe from a C program directly to gdb and see how that works.

Comment: Hmm, it is not? Maybe you have to build yourself. You could write your own GDB-client to control the JTAG-interface. The GDB-protocol is not complicated to implement.

Comment: @Olaf I just assumed that it was difficult to implement a GDB client. Can you direct me to some documents?     for the time being I am on a tight schedule and I think I will just exec("") a new gdb process in a C program and then pipe to the gdb.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It looks like it would have worked.... but.... it gives me the "`evaluation of this expression requires the program to have a function "malloc".`" error, which doesn't make much sense in an embedded context :)  I did a bit of searching but I'm not sure how to work around that.

Comment: @johnny_boy: That might be an option, too, but I don't like such code, it is just complicated to integrate in a whole concept. Just search for "gdb server protocol". You don't have to implement all parts, just the ones you really need (e.g. `monitor`). I'd use Python for such tools. >10 times faster to implement than C or C++. But YMMV.

Comment: @johnny_boy That's odd. `evaluation of this expression requires the program to have a function x` should only happen when using the `print` or `call` command to run a function in the inferior, not when using the `eval` command (unless the args to `eval` ultimately say to do a call). What numeric version of gdb do you have?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That's what I was thinking, but I don't have the gdb experience to dig any deeper. `GNU gdb (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 7.6.0.20140731-cvs` is my version.